# Could we have a leaderboard saying who got the most reputation in a week on the main questions page? or even monthly? top 10 best reputation earners?

Tags: feature-request, status-declined

I was just wandering and it could add to the challenge and enthusiasm of users getting reputation. COuld also increase competition.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

We already do.  If you go to the [Users Page](https://movies.stackexchange.com/users), the list is sorted by reputation.  You can show it for:

- Week
- Month
- Quarter
- Year, or
- All time

See the image below for what it looks like, it defaults to showing the last month.

[image: Image of the controls which allow you to select week, month, quarter, year or all]

(FYI - if you look at it now - the results for week, month and quarter are very similar, as it is July 6 - but later in the month or quarter they will diverge)

As @S S pointed out, we also have [User Reputation Leagues](https://stackexchange.com/leagues/167/year/movies)

Comment: We also have [User reputation leagues](https://stackexchange.com/leagues/167/year/movies).